# How would you print all the strings from an Array that only start with a specified letter?

Tags: java

If you had a list of names in an array

```
 char letter = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);


        for (int i=0; i<Names.length; i++) {
            if(Names[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0)==letter){

                System.out.println(babyNames[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0)==letter);
```

Edit: I don't want it to return a boolean, but the names.

Comment: If your string is named line, then line.startsWith("B") will return true if the first character of line is a capital B.

Comment: Please post your proposal. SO isn't made for doing your homework.

Comment: Just so you know, there is such a thing as [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Reading it would have revealed the `String.startsWith()` method.

Comment: The problem is my attempts so far will only return boolean statements because I am using the chartAt function. I will edit what I have done so far.

Comment: You are already comparing in your if statement, you do not need to compare it again in the System.out.print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can help you to define a structure so that it can determine if a string has the structure or not:

```
if(Pattern.matches("^[Bb].*",str)){
     System.out.println("the str value stated with b");
}
```

Here `^` indicates the beginning of the string to be matches, and `[Bb` means that the string must match an upper- or lowercase letter `B` after that. The `.*` means any character (the dot) zero, one or more times.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a begginer

Comment: Great, that's already much better. I'll edit the answer a a bit for you to give the asker some additional hints.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by iterating on your array through for loop and check the character at first index of every name, if it is 'B' then program should print that name otherwise it continues and move on next name:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {
   "Abby", "Ben", "Bill", "Brian", "Craig", "Cassandra",
   "Collin", "David", "Donny", "Mitchell"
    };

    for (int i =0; i< names.length; i++)
    {
        if (names[i].charAt(0) == 'B')
        {
            System.out.println(names[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can similarly use `startsWith()` which is Java string method:

```
if (names[i].startsWith("B"))
{
     System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Ben                                                                                                                   
Bill                                                                                                                  
Brian
```

Answer (score 0):

when you will use Stream API (Java 8 and newer will be needed):

```
Arrays.stream(names).filter(e -> e.toLowerCase().startsWith("b")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

else you can simply use a for loop with an if statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("b"))
                System.out.println(names[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you! I was trying to use the charAt function because that was my professor used. I didn't know about the startsWith function.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 streams and startsWith.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

public class ArrayStreams { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        // Creating a String array 
        String[] names = {
   "Abby", "Ben", "Bill", "Brian", "Craig", "Cassandra",
   "Collin", "David", "Donny", "Mitchell"
    };

        // Using Arrays.stream() to convert 
        // array into Stream 
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(names); 

        // Displaying elements in Stream 
        stream.forEach(str -> checkString(str + " ")); 
    } 

    public static void checkString(String s){

      if(s.startsWith("B") || s.startsWith("b") )
         System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this , create a function like below

```
private static List<String> getList(String[] names, String pattern) {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        if(names[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(pattern.toLowerCase()))
            temp.add(names[i]);
        }
    return temp;
}
```

If using java-8 you can user stream API

```
private static List<String> getList(String[] names, String pattern) {
  return Arrays.stream(names).filter(name -> name.toLowerCase().startsWith(pattern.toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

then you can specify any alphabet you want to filter your list with

```
String pattern = "b";
```

Then call the function

```
System.out.println(getList(names,pattern));
```

Output

```
[Ben, Bill, Brian]
```

**Note**: You can also modify the getList function to work with `java.util.regex.Pattern`